# CakePHP: Routing Problems

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

All,

I am currently using CakePHP to completely revamp my current NEWS site. I have or will transfer all current articles to my new site and they will take on the same `article_id` as the current site. However, I have realized of the following problem.

My current site uses the following setup as URL:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?c=140&a=4388
```

`c=`references the category ID and `a=`references the article ID. My new setup (CakePHP) I take advantage of slugs and now my articles URLs display as:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/noticia/this-is-an-article-slug
```

Since, I have noticed, thru webstats, that many of my articles are accessed thru links setup on other sites like Facebook, I thought it would be crucial to create a system/route that will take care of this issue for me.

This is what I am thinking:

1. Create a route that detects requests similar to what is mentioned above
2. Make the route pass the `a` value as parameter to a redirect function in my articles controller, such as `articleRedirect($article_id)`
3. This function would then look up in the database for `slug` based on the passed `$article_id` and redirect to the new address (See function below)

   ```
   // Function in articles controller to redirect old site's article url to 
   // new websites url format

   function articleRedirect($article_id = NULL){
       $this->Article->recursive = -1;
       $slug = $this->Article->findById($article_id);        
       if($slug == NULL){
           $this->Session->setFlash('Article not found');
           $this->redirect('/noticias');
       }else{
           $this->redirect('/noticia/'.$slug['Article']['slug']);
       }
   }
   ```

I think that should work. However, I need some serious help with routing. Can anyone suggest a route I can use.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Oldskool for the willingness to help. However, I had trouble implementing it. I decided to stay away from using .htaccess or routes and opted to implement a function in app_controller that will handle it for me as such:

In my `app_controller's` `beforeFilter()` I added the following:

```
//Check old url style as in http://www.bravanews.com/?c=123&a=2345 for redirection
    //to the correct new url style as in http://www.bravanews.com/noticia/news-title-using-slug
    $this->CheckOldUrl();
```

Then in my `app_controller.php` I created the following function:

```
function CheckOldUrl(){
    preg_match("/\?c=(\w+)\&a=(\w+)/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
    if(!$matches == NULL){
        $this->redirect('/noticias/articleRedirect/'.$matches[2]);
    }
}
```

If old url the above function will transfer to the articleRedirect function which will then redirect to the right document

```
// Function in articles controller to redirect old site's article url to 
// new websites url format

function articleRedirect($article_id = NULL){
    $this->Article->recursive = -1;
    $slug = $this->Article->findById($article_id);        
    if($slug == NULL){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Article not found');
        $this->redirect('/noticias');
    }else{
        $this->redirect('/noticia/'.$slug['Article']['slug']);
    }
}
```

It is probably not the best way to handle this kind of things this way since it makes a call to that function everytime time my site is accessed, but it is working for me without major problems.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be re-model your URL's a little bit to still hold the article ID. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/noticia/4388/this-is-an-article-slug
```

Then you can create 1 single RewriteRule to rewrite all old URL's to this new structure and use 1 Route to route them to your controller's action. This way it would only take 2 lines of configuration to migrate old URL's to your new ones. Your route would then look something like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/noticia/:article-id/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'noticias', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('pass' => 'article-id'),
    'article-id' => '[0-9]+'
);
```

That would call the view action of your `NoticiasController` and pass the article id from the URL to it. The RewriteRule you'd have to add to your .htaccess should look something like this (untested, but just to give you a pointer):

```
RewriteRule ^/?c=[0-9]+&a=([0-9]+)$ /noticia/$1/
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. Something might be wrong with the rewrite rule. I will keep on trying different things. Basically nothing happens if I enter www.mydomain.com/?c=135&a=1341. It simply accesses my frontpage.

Comment: @CaboONE Yeah, the Rewrite should probably just be on / With a RewriteCond on the %{QUERY_STRING} variable. Something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=[0-9]+&a=([0-9]+)` with `RewriteRule ^/ /noticia/%1/` might do it.